# Turning a file with string key/values into a Go map

Tags: regex, go

I have a file that contains string key / value pairs separated by an `=` sign.  It looks like this:

```
"some.key" = "A cool value.";
"some.other.key" = "A cool value with %@ chars and \n. Another Thing.";
"escaped.key" = "A cool \"value\".";
"multiline.key.value" = "1. First sentence is "cool"\
2. Second sentence\
3. Third sentence\
4. Fourth sentence";
```

Notice that a value can have escaped quotes inside of them, and they can also span multiple lines.

I've tried basic quote matching, but it doesn't handle the escaped quotes within the values, etc...  Here's what I'm trying at the moment:

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/my/string/file")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

re := regexp.MustCompile(`".*?"`)
match := re.FindAllString(string(file), -1)
fmt.Println(match)
```

Any help would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different approach- You could use a scanner with a custom [split function](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc) to split by your pair delimiter `;` and scan each individual key pair. Then split the key-value pair text by "-" to split your keys and values.

```golang
file, err := os.Open("/my/string/file")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
scanner.Split(customSplitFunc)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println("Key-Value Pair: ", scanner.Text())
    //Split scanner.Text() by "=" to split key and value
}
```

And define customSplitFunc as follows

```
func customSplitFunc(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    if atEOF {
        return len(data), data, nil
    }

    //; followed by newline is the k-v pair delimiter
    if i := strings.Index(string(data), ";\n"); i >= 0 {
        //skip the delimiter in advancing to the next pair
        return i + 2, data[0:i], nil
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Great idea!  One question though: after the custom split function my data is like this:
```
<possible blank line>
/* A comment */
"key" = "value"
```
doing a string.split on that does not work if value is on multiple lines, scanner.Text() just returns 1 line of it :(

Answer (score 2):

I think `(?m)^"([^"]+)"\s*=\s*"(([^"]|(\\")|(\\\n))+)";$` does what you want.
Use that with `FindAllStringSubmatch` and it will return all the matching pairs. Note that if the syntax is invalid on any of the input, the whole thing won't match, so that might not be exactly what you want.

```
func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)^"([^"]+)"\s*=\s*"(([^"]|(\\")|(\\\n))+)";$`)
    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(`"some.key" = "A cool value.";
"some.other.key" = "A cool value with %@ chars and \n. Another Thing.";
"escaped.key" = "A cool \"value\".";
"multiline.key.value" = "1. First sentence is \"cool\"\
2. Second sentence\
3. Third sentence\
4. Fourth sentence";
`, -1)
    for _, m := range matches {
        fmt.Printf("%q %q\n", m[1], m[2])
    }
}
```

(I added the missing backslashes on the fourth line of your input.)

See https://play.golang.org/p/ZHV8jpg17nY.

Answer (score 1):

[`^"(.+?)(?<!\\)"\s*=\s*"([\s\S]*?)(?<!\\)";`](https://regex101.com/r/wMiydw/1) matches keys and values in two groups, assuming they are all in the form `"key" = "value";`. Keys and values can have escaped quotes. Empty keys are not matched.

You can then replace `\\\n` in values with `\n` for values that span multiple lines.

I'm using negative look behind `(?<!\\)` to make sure quotes are not preceded by a backslash.